# QuickBlox Android to iPhone This Video Cannot be Played

Tags: quickblox

I'm using QuickBlox in our chat app. There is a video share feature. When a vidoe file is receieved from Iphone to Android phone via quickblox and opens the file, it gives the error, sorry this video cannot be played. The issue persist when file is received from Android to iPhone too. But it works fine between Iphone to iPhone and Android Phone and Android Phone.

Any Fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to QuickBlox SDK,

This is the issue with Video file format

You should play with video files format and find a one which works on both